# (React Js) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

> ERROR in ./src/pages/Login.jsx 8:0-39
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../hooks/useAuth' in 'C:\Users\Anggur\Downloads\hotelify-dicoding-capstone-main\frontend-react\src\pages'
>
> ERROR in ./src/pages/Login.jsx 9:0-50
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../globals/apiEndpoint' in 'C:\Users\Anggur\Downloads\hotelify-dicoding-capstone-main\frontend-react\src\pages

**Login.js**

> ```
> import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
> import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
> import axios from 'axios';
> import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
> import API_ENDPOINT from '../globals/apiEndpoint';
> import '../index1.css';
> import '../styles/global.css';
> import '../styles/Form.css';
> import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
>
>
> const Login = () => {
>   const emailInput = useRef();
>   const passwordInput = useRef();
>   const navigate = useNavigate();
>   const { login } = useAuth();
>   
>   const submitHandler = async (event) => {
>     event.preventDefault();
>     
>     const sendDataRequest = {
>       email: emailInput.current.value,
>       password: passwordInput.current.value,
>     };
>     
>     try {
>       const response = await axios.post(API_ENDPOINT.LOGIN, sendDataRequest);
>       await Swal.fire({
>         title: 'Berhasil Login',
>         text: 'Berhasil login, silahkan menikmati fitur yang ada ya',
>         icon: 'success',
>         showConfirmButton: false,
>         timer: 2000,
>       });
>       login(response.data);
>       navigate('/');
>     } catch (error) {
>       const errorMessage = error?.response?.data?.message;
>       Swal.fire({
>         title: 'Gagal Login',
>         text: `${errorMessage}`,
>         icon: 'error',
>       });
>     }
>   };
>   
>   return (
>     <>
>       <div className="container py-5">
>         <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center my-5">
>           <form className="col-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4 py-4" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
>             <h1 className="form__title mb-5">Masuk</h1>
>             <div className="row mb-3">
>               <label htmlFor="emailInput" className="form-label">
>                 Email
>                 <input ref={emailInput} type="email" name="email" id="emailInput" className="form-control form__input mt-1" placeholder="Email Anda" required />
>               </label>
>             </div>
>             <div className="row mb-3">
>               <label htmlFor="passwordInput" className="form-label">
>                 Password
>                 <input ref={passwordInput} type="password" name="password" id="passwordInput" className="form-control form__input mt-1" placeholder="Masukkan Password" minLength={8} required />
>                 <div id="passwordHelp" className="form-text">
>                   Panjang password minimal 8 karakter.
>                 </div>
>               </label>
>             </div>
>             <div className="row mb-3 mt-4">
>               <input type="submit" className="mx-auto btn btn-hotelify rounded-pill" value="Masuk" />
>               <p className="text-center mt-3">
>                 Belum punya akun?
>                 {' '}
>                 <Link to="/register" className="hotelify-link pl-2">Daftar</Link>
>               </p>
>             </div>
>           </form>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </>
>   );
> };
>
> export default Login;
> ```

**useAuth.js**

> ```
> import { useContext } from 'react';
> import { AuthContext } from '../store/authContext';
>
> const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
>
> export default useAuth;
> ```

**apiEndpoint.js**

```
import CONFIG from './config';

const API_ENDPOINT = {
  LOGIN: `${CONFIG.BASE_URL}/login`,
  CHECK_TOKEN: `${CONFIG.BASE_URL}/auth/token`,
};

export default API_ENDPOINT;
```

**config.js**

```
const CONFIG = {
    BASE_URL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  };
  
  export default CONFIG;
```

are something wrong with my path? help pls

(React Js) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Comment: yes..try `import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';`

Comment: ERROR in ./src/pages/Login.jsx 8:0-42 Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../hooks/useAuth which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/

Comment: still error like this

Answer (score 0):

We usually use `import` based on relative paths.

`.` and `..` are used the same how we navigate in the terminal while changing directories:

```
cd ..
```

to go up in the directories tree, or

```
mv ../file .
```

to copy `file` from the directory above to the current directory.

Keeping that in mind I see that you actually might have not use the correct  path regarding the module you are trying to use.

Please try changing it from:

```
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
```

to

```
import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';
```

In case of any other errors regarding modules not found, please double-check the directory structure used in the paths in your imports.

Comment: ERROR in ./src/pages/Login.jsx 8:0-42
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../hooks/useAuth which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.     
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/

Comment: still error like this

Comment: Can you please provide the structure of your folders? Can be a `tree` command or can be screenshot as well.